# LINQ Query with Aggregates and Group By

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have the following SQL query...

```
    select  seaMake AS Make,
        seaModel AS Model,
        COUNT(*) AS [Count],
        MIN(seaPrice) AS [From],
        MIN(seaCapId) AS [CapId]
from tblSearch 
where seaPrice >= 2000
and seaPrice <= 7000
group by seaMake, seaModel
order by seaMake, seaModel
```

Im trying to write this as a LINQ to Entities Query, but im having problems. This is what i have so far but i cannot access the make and model values from the var S

```
var tester = from s in db.tblSearches
             where s.seaPrice >= 2000
             && s.seaPrice <= 7000
             orderby s.seaMake
             group s by s.seaMake into g
             select new
             {
                 make = g.seaMake,
                 model = s.seaModel,
                 count = g.Max(x => x.seaMake),
                 PriceFrom = g.Min(s.seaPrice)
              };
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: if you take out your orderby and group by clauses, can you select make/model?

Comment: yes, as the group by will use the var g which doesnt have access to the columns unlike var s

Comment: I guess you can access the `seaMake` using `g.Key`. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a straightforward translation of the SQL:

```
from s in db.tblSearches
where
    s.seaPrice >= 2000 &&
    s.seaPrice <= 7000
group s by new {s.seaMake, s.seaModel} into g
orderby g.Key
select new
{
    Make =  g.Key.seaMake,
    Model = g.Key.seaModel,
    Count = g.Count(),
    From =  g.Min(x => x.seaPrice),
    CapId = g.Min(x => x.seaCapId)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your original collection of `IEnumerable<TypeOfS>` when you *grouped into* g you converted that collection into an IEnumerable> so the collection in current scope is `g`. So the following would be valid

```
from s in db.tblSearches
where s.seaPrice >= 2000
   && s.seaPrice <= 7000
orderby s.seaMake
group s by s.seaMake into g // the collection is now IEnumerable<IGrouping<TypeOfSeaMake, TypeofS>>
select new {
    make = g.Key, // this was populated by s.seaMake
    model = g.First().seaModel, // get the first item in the collection
    count = g.Max(x => x.seaMake), // get the max value from the collection
    PriceFrom = g.Min(x => x.seaPrice), // get the min price from the collection
};
```

there will now be one item returned for each grouping